# ASP.NET DataGrid ItemDataBound Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

DataGrid has 2 events:

ASP.NET DataGrid:

```
ItemCreated 
ItemDataBound
```

When you bind to a data source ItemCreated gets fired followed by ItemDataBound.

I need to know if anyone can think of any good reason of using `ItemCreated`.

I can't find anything versus putting the whole code in `ItemDataBound` event(other than keep the event handler's code  smaller).

Please let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: ItemCreated is basically there for you to interact with UI things, and yes, you can do the exact same thing on the ItemDataBound event as well/create your UI changes there too... i prefere DataBound because then the data is already there.

Comment: Exactly! you cannot put your validation in ItemCreated  since you have no data. Therefore I cannot find any benefits.

Comment: Like i said... mostly for UI stuff (like changing colors, or style the item, or something like that)... that's its sole purpose (that i know of anyway).

Comment: Makes sense. Just to keep UI color and themes separate from data logic . but you can put this same logic in ItemDataBound too. You can post your idea as an answer to this question. Acceptable to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemCreated is basically there for you to interact with UI things, and yes, you can do the exact same thing on the ItemDataBound event as well/create your UI changes there too... i prefer DataBound because then the data is already there, but i understand the purpose of ItemCreated

Answer (score 3):

ItemCreated is fired on the postbacks, but ItemDataBound only during databinding.

Comment: OK. So can you think of actual benefit for this for a binded control?

I think you made a good point.

Answer (score 3):

`ItemCreated` is fired before the data bind actually happens.  You would normally put code dealing with the appearance and non bound content of the grid in this event.

`ItemDataBound` is fired after the data bind.  You would normally put code dealing with the data here.